# Laravel Run JavaScript Inside a Blade

Tags: javascript, laravel

I have a code like this:

```
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" id="activity"></a></li>

<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link {{old('tab') == 'detail' ? 'active' '<script>document.getElementById("activity").classList.remove("active");</script>' : null}}></a>
</li>
```

I want to run that script, but shows me an error. How can I do that?

Comment: I believe you need to put quotes like this: `'<script>document.getElementById("activity").classList.remove("active");</script>'`

Comment: That doesn't work!

Comment: Hey, I've updated the question

Comment: Your syntax is wrong 

`{{old('tab') == 'detail' ? 'active' '<script>document.getElementById("activity").classList.remove("active");</script>' : null}}`

Why do you have two groups of outputs for the true case in your ternary: `'active'` and `'<script>document.getElementById("activity").classList.remove("active");</script>'` Also this isn't best practice to put script inline.

Comment: There is two condition, I should run both of them. `'active'` and that script

Comment: @Khoa check my update code